# Extracting elements from json in python

Tags: python, json

I have the following json:

```
  {
      "request": {
        "id": "123",
        "url": "/aa/bb/cc",
        "method": "GET",
        "timestamp": "2018-08-09T08:41:38.432Z"
      },
      "response": {
        "status": {
          "code": 200,
          "message": "OK"
        },
        "items": [
          {
            "id": "aaa",
            "name": "w1"
          },
          {
            "id": "bbb",
            "name": "w2"
          },
          {
            "id": "ccc",
            "name": "w3"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

I need to loop over `items` and print each `name`. I've tried the following code which doesn't work.

```
response = requests.get(url)
data = json.loads(response.content)

for group in data['response']['items']:
    print data['response']['items'][group]['name']
```

When i replace `group` with 0 for example, I can access the first name:

```
data['response']['items'][0]['name']
```

However, I don't know in advanced how many elements are in the array.

Comment: group is now each dict in `items`, so you can just `print group['name']`. It's **not** the index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Joel mentioned, in the for loop,

```
for group in data['response']['items']:
```

you are assigning `group` the value from `data['response']['items']`. Hence `group` contains the value :

```
[
      {
        "id": "aaa",
        "name": "w1"
      },
      {
        "id": "bbb",
        "name": "w2"
      },
      {
        "id": "ccc",
        "name": "w3"
      }
]
```

So all you need to do is

```
print group['name']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use *Pandas* module and call `read_json` function.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_json(your_json_file.json)

for i in df.response['items']:
    print(i['name'])

# w1
# w2 
# w3
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
for i in range (0,len(d['response']['items'])):
    print(d['response']['items'][i]['name'])
```

Output:

```
w1
w2
w3
```